# Navigation with the Fragment tab host in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment-tab-host

I am currently work on a simple app that based on the fragment tabhost , the structure is like that:

3 tabs total

1. About company
2. Recent News
3. Discuss board

And for example, at the Tab 1 (About company), there is an button call "Company policy", when I click on it , I currently use the CompanyPolicyActivity to implement it.

That means when I open it, I create a new Activity on top of the fragment Activity.

However, **the tab bar is missing if I use Activity**, I wonder are there any way to keep the tabhost bar at new activity / what is the standard way to implement that case e.g. replace fragment? 
(but it seems complex as I need to also handle the switch tab case, eg. return to first fragment when I switch page)

Thanks for helping

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator(""),Home.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("assistant").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_assistant)), Shop.class,null); //not clickable right now
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("coupon").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_coupon)), Coupon.class,null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("shop").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_shop)), Shop.class,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to using getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: if I there in your case, I create tabhost with childfragment too so its mean when I select first tab then first tab create childtab. i hope that's mean in your case

Comment: that means not replace the tab?

Comment: I don't understand what's your purpose. Do you have example familiar apps as a reference?..  Standard of for create tabhost in fragmentactivity, the fragment as mediator. Tabhost calling any the fragment to show what you want. I think make sense.